# AH00052: child pid [PID] exit signal Aborted (6) - Apache error

Tags: apache-2.4, mpm-prefork

I have an installation of **Apache/2.4.18** running on **Ubuntu 16.04**. Apache is configured as Prefork MPM. **PHP 7.0.22**

Checking the error log at /var/log/apache2/error.log I see lots of these errors:

```
[Fri Jan 26 12:59:20.223248 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7203] AH00052: child pid 19370 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Fri Jan 26 13:39:20.475386 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7203] AH00052: child pid 24060 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Fri Jan 26 13:44:07.739520 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7203] AH00052: child pid 26568 exit signal Aborted (6)
[Fri Jan 26 13:44:17.748513 2018] [core:notice] [pid 7203] AH00052: child pid 6630 exit signal Aborted (6)
```

Other than these errors, the log is clean.

The available memory is not an issue, as I can see in top and free. Moreover, the current configuration of apache will not use more than 50% aprox. of the RAM available (other services included).

Googling around didn't provide any usable results. There is also [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/859800/httpd-exit-signal-aborted-after-dist-upgrade) but with no answer and apart from that it's not the same case as mine.

Apache is hosting some web sites, which don't **seem** to be affected by these errors.

Any ideas what the problem is and how it can be solved?

Comment: Are these PHP processes that are dying? Look for PHP errors in the log around the same time, and you may want to turn up the PHP [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) level.

Answer (score 1):

It could be PHP modules like APC or XCache, try to disable then and verify if it solve.